# Why is ref needed in this case?

Tags: c#, .net

I was looking at the reference source and found NumberToInt32:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,a2e15b1a0fe0c25c

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
internal unsafe static Int32 ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) {

    Byte * numberBufferBytes = stackalloc Byte[NumberBuffer.NumberBufferBytes];
    NumberBuffer number = new NumberBuffer(numberBufferBytes);
    Int32 i = 0;

    StringToNumber(s, style, ref number, info, false);

    if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != 0) {
        if (!HexNumberToInt32(ref number, ref i)) { 
            throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!NumberToInt32(ref number, ref i)) {
            throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
        }
    }
    return i;           
}

[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
private unsafe static Boolean NumberToInt32(ref NumberBuffer number, ref Int32 value) {

    Int32 i = number.scale;
    if (i > Int32Precision || i < number.precision) {
        return false;
    }
    char * p = number.digits;
    Contract.Assert(p != null, "");
    Int32 n = 0;
    while (--i >= 0) {
        if ((UInt32)n > (0x7FFFFFFF / 10)) {
            return false;
        }
        n *= 10;
        if (*p != '\0') {
            n += (Int32)(*p++ - '0');
        }
    }
    if (number.sign) {
        n = -n;
        if (n > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (n < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    value = n;
    return true;
}
```

What is the reason that `NumberToInt32` uses the `ref` keyword to number?
The number seems unchanged in the function.

Comment: Considering it's run in an unsafe context and very low level functions, they're trying to conserve memory or perf reasons. Those buffers are on the stack and they wouldn't want to copy those around.

Comment: The NumberBuffer declaration is essential. Class and Structure objects are handled [differently](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx). See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171842/does-passing-reference-types-using-ref-save-memory) SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `NumberBuffer` source you'll notice the structure has five fields making it pretty large to be copied. So the idea to use `ref` here is just speed optimization. You don't have to modify any `ref` parameters just because you can.